# Complex example about accessing multiples SQLite tables from Android

Tags: android, sqlite, frameworks

I'm developing an Android application that access many tables from a SQLite database.

I need an example to see how implement a database framework to access multiples tables. I've been looking for and I only find examples with one table.

**UPDATE**:

With one table I found only one class `DBAdpater` with object `SQLiteDatabase` and a `class myDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper`.

With many tables I think I need one `DBAdapter` for each table. So, I think I need to share SQLiteDatabase object between each DBAdapter, isn't it? To open database, close, execute SQL stament...

I think I need one DBAdapter because I don't want a enormous DBAdapter class.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see the difference between doing it with one table and N tables? More important thing is to understand how Sqlite works on Android... if you do understand, then you have it done.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details.